# Run a php app using tomcat?

Tags: php, tomcat, apache

Is it possible to run a PHP app using tomcat?

Before you tell me to just use httpd, I already have a Java application running on my webserver at `host/myapp`. Now I want to install RoundCube at host/roundcube.

One is PHP and one is Java. I keep seeing offhand references saying this is possible but no real instructions. I do not want to put them on separate ports, I need the standard HTTP and HTTPS ports.

Does anyone have any resources for this?

Answer (score 46):

Yes it is Possible [Will Den](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17614/will-den). we can run PHP code in tomcat server using it's own port number localhost:8080

here I'm writing some step which is so much useful for you.

**How to install or run PHP on Tomcat 6 in windows**

1. download and unzip PHP 5 to a directory, `c:\php-5.2.6-Win32` - [php-5.2.9-2-Win32.zip Download](http://www.php.net/get/php-5.2.9-2-Win32.zip/from/a/mirror)
2. download **PECL 5.2.5 Win32** binaries - [PECL 5.2.5 Win32 Download](http://museum.php.net/php5/pecl-5.2.5-Win32.zip)
3. rename `php.ini-dist` to `php.ini` in `c:\php-5.2.6-Win32`
4. Uncomment or add the line (remove semi-colon at the beginning) in `php.ini`:
   `;extension=php_java.dll`
5. copy `php5servlet.dll` from PECL 5.2.5 to `c:\php-5.2.6-Win32`
6. copy `php_java.dll` from **PECL 5.2.5** to `c:\php-5.2.6-Win32\ext`
7. copy `php_java.jar` from **PECL 5.2.5** to `tomcat\lib`
8. create a directory named `"php"` (or what ever u like) in `tomcat\webapps` directory
9. copy `phpsrvlt.jar` from **PECL 5.2.5** to `tomcat\webapps\php\WEB-INF\lib`
10. Unjar or unzip `phpsrvlt.jar` for unzip use winrar or winzip for unjar use : `jar xfv phpsrvlt.jar`
11. change both `net\php\reflect.properties` and `net\php\servlet.properties` to `library=php5servlet`
12. Recreate the jar file
    -> jar cvf php5srvlt.jar net/php/*.*
    PS: if the jar file doesnt run you have to add the Path to system variables for me I added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin; to System variables/Path`
13. create `web.xml` in `tomcat\webapps\php\WEB-INF` with this content:

    ```
    <web-app version="2.4" 
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance "
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd ">
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>php</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>net.php.servlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>php-formatter</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>net.php.formatter</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>php</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>php-formatter</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.phps</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
    ```
14. Add PHP path( `c:\php-5.2.6-Win32`) to your System or User Path in Windows enironment (Hint: Right-click and select Properties from **My Computer**
15. create `test.php` for testing under `tomcat\webapps\php` like
16. Restart tomcat
17. browse `localhost:8080/php/test.php`

Comment: +1 for this nice tutorial. It works, after I added a missing step. The missing step is: copy **php_java.jar** from **PECL 5.2.5** to **tomcat\lib** dir.

Comment: I hope you can also write for 64 bit :)

Comment: Does anybody have any idea about the performance (compared to run php script within apache http server) ?

Comment: Looks like there is typos in xmlns definition

Answer (score 32):

It's quite common to run Tomcat behind Apache. In Apache you can then direct certain URLs to Tomcat, and have Apache/PHP handle the others (including the static images).

(On Unix, Tomcat itself cannot securely made to run on port 80, while Apache can. Tomcat, being a Java process, would be required to run as root, while Apache will switch to non-root privileges as soon as port 80 has been claimed. So, running Apache on port 80 and have it redirect some or all requests to Tomcat, is quite common on Unix.)

Comment: This is definitely the simplest option. 

For calling Tomcat from Apache you should have a look at the Apache mod_jk module.

Comment: Of course you can run tomcat on port 80 on Unix without being root. Just use iptables to redirect port 80 to port 8080.

Comment: @Kim, I'd not classify using iptables as running Tomcat on port 80, but you're right: using Apache is not the only option. (Using Apache does have other benefits though, like serving static content. My statement "is to be preferred" was certainly a bit too simplified.)

Comment: Nowadays, in Ubuntu 10.04 Tomcat is configured with authbind to use ports under 1024 and works very nicely. Using Quercus you can also run some (most) PHP scripts without a hitch.

Answer (score 7):

Caucho [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/) can run PHP code on the jvm.

Comment: True, but don't you have to use Caucho Resin?

Comment: That worked really well.  I tried the solution provided under the title of "How to install or run PHP on Tomcat 6 in windows", failed miserably.

Answer (score 6):

There this [PHP/Java](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) bridge. This is basically running PHP via FastCGI. I have not used it myself.

Comment: Did not work,  This one does:  http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/.  Downloaded the war file.  Put in into the webapps directory which exploded the war file nicely.  Ran startup from tomcat's bin, bingo.

Comment: For future seekers, Works just fine with jdk1.8 tomcat 9 and (php the latest version)

Answer (score 6):

A tad late, but here goes.

How about http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/UsingPhp if you just want to run the real php on tomcat.

Concerning running tomcat on port 80 there's always jsvc, just google jsvc + tomcat.

Answer (score 3):

tomcat is designed as JSP servlet container. Apache is designed PHP web server. Use apache as web server, responding for PHP request, and direct JSP servlet request to tomcat container. should be better implementation.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone's still looking - 
[Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) has a war that allows to run PHP scripts in apache tomcat or glassfish. For a step by step guide look at [this](http://www.studytrails.com/blog/php-on-a-java-app-server-apache-tomcat-using-quercus/) article

Comment: I did not even need the nicely written article but did preview it.  Just grabbed the war file.

Comment: Quercus is no longer getting developed. It's has PHP-5 only. So if you are looking to run any framework like wordpress which is looking for PHP-7 then this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have php installed on your server
2. Find the latest release of php-java-bridge off of [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge/files/Binary%20package/)
3. From the exploded directory on Sourceforge, download `php-servlet.jar` and `JavaBridge.jar`
4. Place those jar files into `webapp/WEB-INF/lib` folder of your project
5. Edit webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml to look like:

ok

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>PhpCGIFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>PhpCGIFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <!-- the following adds the JSR223 listener. Remove it if you don't want to use the JSR223 API -->
   <listener>
      <listener-class>php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <!-- the back end for external (console, Apache/IIS-) PHP scripts; remove it if you don't need this -->
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <!-- runs PHP scripts in this web app; remove it if you don't need this -->
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.phpjavabridge</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

You may have other content inside this file, just make sure you have added everything between the web-app tag.

6. Add your php files to the webapp directory

You can do other special things with this as well. You cal learn more about it here: http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/how_it_works.php