# mysql_connect error

Tags: php

In the following code I see `echo1` statement, after which I do not see anything printed on the UI.The username and password is correct. But PHP doesn't seem to connect to MySQL. Don't even see the die statement what am I doing wrong. After `mysql_connect` is encountered the rest of the code doesn't work:

```
<?php    
echo "echo1==========";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "xxxx123") or die("Error connecting to database");
echo "+++++++++ echo2";
echo $con;
mysql_close($con);
  ?>
```

Comment: Try to use `'` instead of `"`, e.g. `mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');` Try it and let me know! I will elaborate!

Comment: Do you have your `error reporting` turned on?

Comment: Also try ..or die(mysql_error()); to get more information..

Comment: @Ilia Rostovtsev: it doesn't matter. The problem is that the error reporting is turned off. Rajeev, turn on the error reporting then you will se what is the problem but please do not use the mysql_ stuffess, try PDO or mysqli_

Comment: After turning on the reporting i get Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Comment: @Rajeev which server are you using..??

Comment: @Rajeev Yes... what PHP? 5.4... consider using MySQLi (objects) now. MySQL (resources) is no longer supported.

Comment: Now if i use mysql i get the error as Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: sudo apt-get install php5-mysqli is obsolete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the ph5-mysql driver was not installed .Installed it and got it working..Now mysql_connect() function works..Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 4):

You should be mising an error. Add :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the beggining of your script

Comment: It is, the problem was "I see only echo1, why don't I see the rest ?"

Answer (score 1):

No output means a fatal error. The only possible fatal error is "undefined function `mysql_connect` (unless something's really messed up somewhere). This means the `mysql` library is not installed, or it might just not be enabled in the `php.ini` file.

Check said file, and while you're at it turn `error_reporting` on.

Comment: I think so but i am not sure what changes has to be done in php.ini

Comment: Well, that would depend on if you are running Windows or Linux. If it's Windows, you need to add the appropriate DLL to the list of extensions. If it's Linux... I have no clue. Your webhost may be able to help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your code just like this then it's vulnerable for SQL Injection. I would strongly recommend using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) as you insert data into your database to prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939226/sql-injections-and-adodb-library-general-php-website-security-with-examples/11941396), as a quick solution or better use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

If you are going to use `mysql_*` then I'd recommend reading the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions,
where they point out, that this extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, they say, you should use either the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension.

I also checked `mysql_connect` and found a weird regularity which is - if you use `"` on `mysql_connect` arguments, then it fails to connect and in my case, when I was testing it,  it happened just described way, so, please try this instead:

`$con = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');`

Replace `"` to `'` as it's shown in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) examples and it might work!

**EDITED**

For those who downvote - *TRY* first! I tested it on my server with `"` and it gave me an error: **`Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user`**. I use PHP version 5.4.6!

Login to your server with SSH and run `php --modules` - if you don't see `mysql` in the list - then it's the reason of your fatal error.

Comment: Now the error is Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/dbconnect.php on line 13

Comment: May I ask how the OP's code is even remotely vulnerable to injection when there is absolutely no user input involved? And what difference will single quotes make over double quotes when there isn't a variable interpolation in sight? Do you even know what you're talking about?

Comment: @Kolink yes i just turned on the error reporting and i go the error.Yes it doesnt matter with single or double quotes

Comment: @Kolink `mysql_connect` implies that the rest will be used! That is why. There is no reason to build a project on deprecated and vulnerable `mysql_` extension.

Comment: @Kolink I tried on my server few months ago putting `mysql_connect` in double quotes and it didn't work. I tested it many times - that's why I have written it! It didn't come out of the blue! I think it's the unnoticed bug!

Comment: And the fact that I've always used double-quotes without any issues is meaningless, I guess? Do you really think such a basic matter as string delimiters would be an unfixed bug?

Comment: @Kolink, my friend, you're not listening! I don't think! It's the fact, at least for my server for sure! Try it on your server and let me know if it's true for you!

Comment: @Kolink: I personally treat all `mysql_*` functions as vulnerable to SQL injection by default. Whether an actual query is involved or not. For me it's another "excuse" to get the user moving away from it, fast.

Comment: @Madara Uchiha Totally agree. Programming is about beauty (for me) not just about getting the desired result! The server part is not seen but it has to be done and organized nicely from the very first step!

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev: It is seen, by other developers in the future, maintaining your code, or even future you. As someone wiser than me once said, *be nice to future you*.

Comment: Well, I would gladly move to prepared statements... but then I see all the SO questions asking how to do something with prepared statements that would be extremely easy in plain MySQL (most frequently selecting a column that is not known ahead of time) and I think "Meh, I'd rather just know the safety risks and sanitise everything."

Comment: Using double or single quotes has absolutely no relevance to this problem whatsoever. Come on.... the only time it has relevance is when you use variables within the string, such as `"$user"`, but why would you do that.

Comment: @eis I would think the same if I didn't try it myself 3 times in a row on different days! Check it yourself and you might encounter the same! ;) I'm positive on that! I don't know the reason why it's happening but it's just the way it is! No variables just plain username and password. Actually, just found out, if a field (username or password) has special characters than what I'm talking about applies!

Comment: I tested just to humor and there is no difference. Why in the world would there be? Can you provide an example how it is for you?

Comment: @eis Again, I tested it and for the world's sake I don't know the reason why but there is in my case! If you used password like `123` I think it's not applicable in this case! Use as password something like  `$n]v$t@-Ho#;%X5?J3TGUi$?` and then you could see the difference! May be not but again don't ask me why because I'm just like you - surprised to see the difference. My PHP version is 5.4.6 by the way.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev see my comment about variables in the string, you have `$` in there... it needs to be escaped properly

Comment: @eis Thanks, that's the case, I think. It's better to use single quote to make it universally applicable!

Answer (score 0):

For Tomcat 7, the default dir for php.ini is actually C:\windows. So modified (enabling modules, extensions etc.) php.ini should be copied to C:\windows. Then run phpinfo();. It should work fine even on Tomcat 7 along side PHP 5.x. I had this problem and struggled a lot when I wanted the mysql statements to work.

Even after following all instructions from answers in [779246] ([Run a php app using tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat)), mysql statements didn't work (Tomcat 7, PHP 5.2.16, PECL 5.2.5, MySql 5.6 on Windows 7). So I started looking into "phpinfo();" output carefully and used solution as mentioned in earlier paragraph. Please be sure to enable mysql dll extension and also PDO extensions in php.ini if you would like to use PDO (which is future of plain mysql_* methods in PHP).