# PHP and mysql integration with apache tomcat 6 in linux

Tags: php, linux, tomcat6

I am using apache tomcat 6 in my application. I want to provide support for executing PHP files in apache tomcat 6 on Linux. I don't want to install PHP separately on my machine, but provide PHP modules(.so files) as a part of apache/modules. As tomcat 6 does not have httpd.conf file, i am not able to load PHP modules through the following directive in httpd.conf file-

LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so

Can anyone help me in loading php module in tomcat 6 on linux? Please also let me know if some other configurations are required for providing this support on linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use XAMPP server?

Answer (score 0):

just shooting:
http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/UsingPhp

Or, even better solution seems to me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/779255/1408096

helpful?

Comment: Using the above link, i followed the procedure to create the phpsrvlt.jar and libphp4.so file. However, I got the following error
during make command

/Apache_Fix/php-4.3.5RC2/sapi/cli/php_cli.c:94: error: static declaration of 'optarg' follows non-static declaration
/usr/include/getopt.h:59: note: previous declaration of 'optarg' was here
/Apache_Fix/php-4.3.5RC2/sapi/cli/php_cli.c:95: error: static declaration of 'optind' follows non-static declaration
/usr/include/getopt.h:73: note: previous declaration of 'optind' was here
make: *** [sapi/cli/php_cli.lo] Error 1

Comment: I searched for this error and found that this error is thrown by compiler gcc 4.x but not by gcc 3.2.3. I am using centOS 6 and gcc 4.x is the default one with centOS 6. I tried to install gcc 3.2.3 on centOS 6 but no luck

Comment: @paresh it looks like you are using older OS with some newer apps/libraries. I think the best thing to do, is to install some already compiled package as Sumit Munot has proposed already, or you need to updated all the necessary libraries (gcc,...) in your linux distribution - this option would be quite time and resource-demanding, however.