# Where should i place the php files (Web Service) in Apache tomcat 7?

Tags: php, database, web-services, tomcat

I am creating an android app .. For that i need to call a web service to access the database .. The language that i have chosen for the web service php !

Comment: See , i am trying to connect to mySQL database using a PHP webservice ! For that i need to find a solution!

Comment: hello. welcome to SO. please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). if you decide to post code please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Stop using exclamation marks! They’re not needed! You can place the scripts any where! It’s just a normal web server!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a php app using tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat)

Comment: found the solution. I was using a wamp server , so made a change to the config file of the apache server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere. To quote [the homepage](http://tomcat.apache.org/): *Apache Tomcat is an open source software implementation of the Java Servlet and JavaServer Pages technologies*. It is geared very heavily towards running Java programs and, as far as I know, can't execute PHP. (I did find [this wiki entry](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/UsingPhp) which explains how to make an ancient, unsupported version of PHP work under Tomcat by editing PHP's source code and recompiling it. Don't use Tomcat for PHP!)

If you want to run PHP, then use a server suited for it, such as [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org/) with [mod_php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) or [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) with [FastCGI](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.lighttpd-14.php).

If you really, really want to run PHP through Tomcat, then you can do so via [CGI](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cgi-howto.html). I wouldn't recommend it though, CGI isn't very efficient.

If you want to run Java applications with Tomcat side-by-side with PHP apps, then make a normal HTTPD the one that end clients connect to. It can handle the PHP. Use it as [a proxy](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html) to the Tomcat server when you want to run Java.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just need the directory , the php files should be put up in.

Comment: @user2157442 — There is no such directory.

Comment: I downloaded Apache Tomacat , It came in a rar format , so i extracted it.. I need to place the php files somewhere in the folder rite ?

Comment: @user2157442 — No. Tomcat **does not** handle PHP. You need a different web server.