# PHP in the page doesn't get parsed when I try to access the page using HTTP

Tags: java, php, jakarta-ee, netbeans

PHP doesn't get parsed when I try to run the PHP page. I am using NetBeans and running Apache Tomcat as the server. I have defined the interpreter for PHP which is shown in the following snapshot:

[image]

If I try to run the PHP page from within the IDE *(by using the default shift+F6)*, it runs, but with a URL `file:///C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/php_1.php11992.html` for a file named `php_1.php`. But when I try to test the URL `localhost:8081/app/php_1.php`, the PHP in the page isn't parsed, and I see only the HTML getting parsed.

What could be the reason for this? What do I do to parse PHP directly ?

*Note:* I have installed `XAMPP`, and the path I give in the above snapshot is of the PHP interpreter that comes packed with the XAMPP package.

Comment: isn't tomcat for JSP? though i believe you can set them side by side by specifying certain rules on the urls.. a quick search showed me this. hopefully this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the tomcat webserver is stopped and the XAMPP server running, since there could be a conflict (of ports, URIs etc).

If XAMPP is running and it still doesn't work, you can try the following:

Ensure the webserver has the type set in conf.d:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .phtml
```

Also, if you are using short tags make sure it is enabled in php.ini

Make sure mod_php is enabled in XAMPP (should be by default). You can do this by navigating to httpd.exe in XAMPP and typing httpd -M which will list currently used modules.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding a concept.But what is the need to start `xampp` ? I am already running `tomcat` from netbeans.