# PHP on Tomcat 8

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, webserver, tomcat8

I had found quite a few guides how to make PHP run on Tomcat, but all were on previous versions. I tried all of them and all I could manage to display is a blank page and the code is still not fired.

I understand that Tomcat is build for Java application and not PHP, but I need to find a way to do that with Tomcat 8. Does any of you know a resource that could help me with this?
I tried the guides in the following links, but without luck:

http://tojackwu.blogspot.com/2008/10/php-5-on-tomcat-6-installation.html

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/tomcat6.php

Any idea if this is possible with Tomcat 8 and how can I do it?

OS: Windows;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet to run PHP on top of Tomcat is probably to download and install the Quercus WAR file.  Quercus is a Java-based implementation of PHP 5, and it can be found at http://quercus.caucho.com/.

Comment: here you can find a small tutorial to use it: http://www.studytrails.com/blog/php-on-a-java-app-server-apache-tomcat-using-quercus/

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the guide from: http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/webapp.php

The above has been verified in TomEE, which is based on Tomcat

Note that Tomcat 8 still contains a bug. As a workaround you'll need to add an empty "java" directory to the JavaBridgeTemplate.war zip file:

```
drwxr-xr-x         0  31-Oct-2010  15:24:24  WEB-INF/
-rw-r--r--       239  31-Oct-2010  15:20:30  WEB-INF/weblogic.xml
drwxr-xr-x         0  31-Oct-2010  15:24:24  WEB-INF/lib/
-rw-r--r--    436954  31-Oct-2010  15:24:24  WEB-INF/lib/JavaBridge.jar
-rw-r--r--     58673  31-Oct-2010  15:24:24  WEB-INF/lib/php-script.jar
-rw-r--r--     58252  31-Oct-2010  15:24:24  WEB-INF/lib/php-servlet.jar
-rw-rw-r--      3871  31-Oct-2010  15:24:50  index.php
-rwxrwxr-x        19  31-Oct-2010  15:24:50  test.php
-rw-rw-r--      1779  31-Oct-2010  15:24:50  WEB-INF/web.xml
drwxr-xr-x         0  25-Apr-2016  20:53:10  java/
```

Comment: Added more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat/51665443#51665443