# how to run or install Joomla on tomacat5 server?

Tags: joomla3.2

how can I run a Joomla website on tomcat. now I had used XAMPP for creating the website. now I am going to host this on a tomcat5 server whether I can host a Joomla website on tomacat5?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in other **[questions / answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat)** or some [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/UsingPhp) you can certainly run PHP on tomcat.

There is also a php-java-bridge you may want to look into.

But I am not sure why you would want to do that. Generally you would want to run Joomla on an Apache server, especially from the support point of view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The documentation is giving me steps of tomcat6 . but i have a tomcat5 server is it possible with the same documentation.that document is for the windows i am using a linux server

Comment: please help me in this