# Can I use JSP Based Chat Application in PHP website?

Tags: php, jsp, chat

May be its silly question, but I want to know that Is there any way to use JSP-SQL based chat application on existing PHP-MySQL website?

Comment: If you install Tomcat alongside Apache/PHP then sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on environment, do u have web server that supports both php and jsp? You need to have php module on in apache and u have servlet container like tomcat on the same apache to be able to do it. Why do not u just use php since the app will be part of php/mysql web site?

Comment: i don't know it. i am using xampp 1.8.2 server. Does it support JSP? @Elbek

Comment: No, it does not. Xampp is just apache itself

Comment: so, is there any solution?

Comment: There is, but is requires some admin work on server. Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat