# install PHP on Tomcat 7 in windows

Tags: java, php, tomcat

I tried to install PHP5.2.16 on Tomcat 7 using PECL5.2.5, I followed all steps from here: [Run a php app using tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat), posted by Saunik Singh, but I get an error and I have no idea how to solve it.

ROOT CAUSE
java.lang.classnotfoundexception net.php.servlet

Could you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: You're missing the library that contains `net.php.Servlet`.

Comment: as commented on the answer.. have you added `php_java.jar from PECL 5.2.5 to tomcat\lib dir.`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys. I solevd the issue : I have installed Java JDK instead of Java JRE and I used jar.exe in windows command line to unjar/re-jar the phpsrvlt.jar.
I think the the issue was caused by the incorrect re-jar.