# Unable to run PHP script from HTMl Submit button in Linux

Tags: php, html, linux

I am trying to run a PHP script from when submit button is clicked in my HTML code. I installed tomcat server on my remote linux server and its running fine. I even tested running sample PHP on it and its fine. I have tried below code on my local desktop and able to run the php script without any issues.

But when i run it from my remote linux server, the output when i am clicking the submit button is the PHP script itself on the page. Not able to understand exact mistake. Kindly guide me. Thanks.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id = "button" value="submit"  >Submit</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#button').click(function () {
        alert("first")
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: "http://localhost:8085/ElitePass/login.php",
            data: {

                stime: $("#demo1").val(),
                etime: $("#demo2").val(),
                desc: $("#servername").val()
            },

            success: function(data){
                alert(data)
                $('#resultip').html(data);
            },
            error:function(data)
            {
                alert("Data sending failed");
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `url: "http://localhost:8085/ElitePass/login.php",` on remote server? Hmmmm

Comment: If you get the PHP script as output that means your remote server probably does not have PHP CGI configured correctly. Can you tell us what server software and version you are running?

Comment: Could be a short tag issue (`<?` vs `<?php`).  Probably more likely your tomcat setup.  Easier to use httpd.

Comment: @hyde i am using Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

Comment: You need to enable PHP CGI if it's not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is misconfigured and the pages are not being executed, you may have permission problems, and also if you want to go cross-domain you should take a look for [CORS policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
Take a look at this

> **[question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat)** about using PHP and TOMCAT