# How to run php on tomcat 7 server ( CentOS )

Tags: php, tomcat, tomcat7

I want to run PHP on tomcat 7 server in root directory.. 
Which means by running localhost:8080. `index.php` file should load.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Java Wrapper for PHP to do that. Tomcat can only run Java.
See here for some outdated instructions for PHP 5.2 and Tomcat 6: [Run a php app using tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat)

However if you're just looking to run a PHP and Java App on the same port, you'd probably be better off by just adding a reverse proxy in front of Httpd and Tomcat, keeping the PHP and plain HTML separate from the Java stuff.
(This is the way 99.9999% of the people will do this in production setups)