# HTTP Status 500 Tomcat

Tags: php, apache, tomcat

After going through this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat) and going to the created URL (localhost:8080/php/test.php), I get this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: net.php.servlet.send(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Z)V
    net.php.servlet.send(Native Method)
    net.php.servlet.service(servlet.java:190)
    net.php.servlet.service(servlet.java:214)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.73 logs.
```

I installed PHP 7 instead and followed the tutorial. What should I do in order for the PHP pages to be rendered?

Comment: `The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.73 logs.`

Comment: @u_mulder what am I doing wrong though?

Comment: Open logs and read a detail error.