# Contact form showing PHP file

Tags: php, html, email

Currently I'm developing a contact form on my website. Here I'm attaching my code

**HTMl file**

```
<form action="php/contacts-process.php"  class="contacts-process" method="post"  novalidate="novalidate">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="7" name="message" ></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                        <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="SEND MESSAGE">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**PHP file**

```
<?php
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
error_reporting(0);

if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
    if ($_REQUEST['action'] == "email_server_responce") {
        $ourMail = "xyz@gmail.com"; //Insert your email address here
        $pre_messagebody_info = "";
        $errors = array();
        $data = array();
        parse_str($_REQUEST['values'], $data);

        $result = array(
            "is_errors" => 0,
            "info" => ""
        );

        if (!empty($errors)) {
            $result['is_errors'] = 1;
            $result['info'] = $errors;
            echo json_encode($result);
            exit;
        }

        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers.= "From: ".$data['email']."\r\n";
        $pre_messagebody_info.="<strong>Name</strong>" . ": " . $data['name'] . "<br />";
        if (! empty($data['email']) ) {
            $pre_messagebody_info.="<strong>E-mail</strong>" . ": " . $data['email'] . "<br />";
        }
        if (! empty($data['phone']) ) {
            $pre_messagebody_info.="<strong>Phone</strong>" . ": " . $data['phone'] . "<br />";
        }
        if (! empty($data['url']) ) {
            $pre_messagebody_info.="<strong>URL</strong>" . ": " . $data['url'] . "<br />";
        }
        if (empty($data['subject']) ) {
            $subject = "Website Contact Form";
        } else {
            $subject = $data['subject'];
        }
        $after_message = "\r\n<br />--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n<br /> This mail was sent via contact form";

        if (mail($ourMail, $subject, $pre_messagebody_info .= $category . "<strong>Message</strong>" . ": " . $data['message'] .$after_message, $headers)) {
            $result["info"] = "success";
        } else {
            $result["info"] = "server_fail";
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit;
    }
} ?>
```

When I Clicked on Submit button it showing php code on my browser. I'm not able to figure out the what's wrong in my code. I'm running through tomcat server. Could any one review it and please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is php working on your server?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat check this

Comment: xampp or wamp running  ?

Comment: i'm using wamp server

Answer (score 0):

The server is not correctly configured to run php ;)

You can check the reference [Run a php app using tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat) which is suggested by @Ahmed Sunny