# How do I run a PHP project in TomCat?

Tags: php, tomcat, web-deployment

I have a PHP web site project and in the company I work they use just TomCat. I want to deploy my php project with its configuration and extensions to the tomcat server.

To connect to the Data Base (SQL-Server 2012) I've used the SQL driver (Microsoft). I have included in my local host server (XAMP) some php extensions. My other questions is how do i deploy the all project and its configurations?!

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? [Start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+tomcat).

Comment: I have concluded the code, using sublime... I have executed it in locahost using XAMP. Now i want to deploy the site in the company tomcat machine. But i dont know how to do that because i ve instal some php extension in the localhost server and instal the DB driver.

Comment: My point is how to deploy the site on the tomcat with the php extensions and the drivers i've instal

Comment: Hi Menino Hori. A similar question has been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a php app using tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat)

Comment: Then surely your question should be about specifically how to install the same PHP extensions into tomcat? It would be good if you mention the exact extensions. Does the tomcat server you're targeting already support vanilla PHP? Or do you need to install that too - and do you know how to do it, or not? Also, mention the target O/S. Like I said, it's a bit unclear precisely what the situation is. If you ask a vague question, you will get more questions in return and/or vague, generic answers.

Comment: It does not answer my question... In the oter question the guy have already put the php script on the tomcat.

Comment: Sorry if im not being clear. How do i can put my localhost php application into tomCat server?

Comment: The tomCat is running in the Windows server 2012, the extension that i've instal on localhost is extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll e extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll and SQL