# How to run PHP in Apache Tomcat 9?

Tags: php, tomcat

I want to run my php code in Tomcat9, but Tomcat has no support for php. I tried following this guide but it didn't work `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat`

Is there any other way that can help me to run PHP in Apache Tomcat?

Comment: tomcat is for java, not for PHP or python or c or anything else. I really don't understand why you want to do that.

Comment: @svgta I have a webgis project running on Tomcat and connect to PostgreSQL via GeoServer, but now I want to connect directly to PostgreSQL, I wrote php code to do it so now I hope to be able to run that PHP code in tomcat.

Comment: That post is 13 years old - it was a bad idea back then and it's worse now.  You cannot realistically run PHP in Tomcat.  One thing you can look at is using something like Apache HTTPD to act as a PHP server and as a proxy server to Tomcat.

Comment: Why do you want to run php in tomcat instead of Apache? By any chance are you confusing Apache Tomcat with Apache webserver?

Comment: @Usman Mutawakil looks like I was really confused, I'm using apache tomcat9. So is there any way to do that? Thanks you.

Comment: @Jayzz Why are you using Apache Tomcat and not Apache Webserver for PHP?

Comment: @Usman Mutawakil as I said in the previous comment, I have a webgis with javascript code running on Apache Tomcat so I am forced to insert my php code there

Comment: I see.  You might want to add that into your description. I think thats why someone voted to close it....Is it a lot of PHP code? It might be easier to just write a war file in java and deploy that into the same container. Is your goal only to communicate with the Postgress database? If so why not run your php code in a separate server and use the same database credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use quercus (https://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp) , get it at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dCvrrTHepkpqf0PmO-fbFlfKp-cY2663/view

See step-by-step guide at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seQHzVwUdYo